# The word for "unable to change"

Tags: word-request

Is there any word in English for a person who is unable to change himself for someone else regardless of he/she wants to change or not? He just can't change.

I'm writing a play and I need that word for a specific scene if there's any. The scene is, boy B and girl G are in love. Both love each other. But the problem is B can't change his bad habits like smoking and gambling etc. But sure he wants to change. But he's just too addicted and he can't. So G will get the dialog "Look I still love you, but you are too [something something]. You can't change yourself even for your love". I need something to fill in brackets. I thought of stubborn.

Comment: We do have the word **unchangeable**.

Comment: **Adamant**? Your question is unclear.

Comment: **Inflexible**?  **Hidebound**?

Comment: Recalcitrant? Perhaps?

Comment: Imalleable is related. Immutable.

Comment: @Spark _You are too **set in your ways!**_

Comment: Not for people, but an object which cannot be changed is `immutable` (from the Latin)

Answer (score 1):

- **Inflexible** - unwilling to change or compromise.

  By conscious choice someone is unwilling to change. 

  *"We must have Christmas dinner at his house every year. He is completely inflexible to having anywhere else."*
- **Unmovable** - incapable of being moved. 

  Can apply to inanimate objects as well as people as simply a state of being. 

  "The tree is unmovable therefore we must build the path around it."
- **Independent** - not influenced or controlled by others. 

  Mostly a positive characteristic of someone who is self-sufficient.

  *"She's very independent. She finishes her homework and chores without ever being asked to."*
- **Unbending** - rigid; refusing to bend or compromise. 

  Can apply to inanimate objects as well as people as simply a state of being.

  *"The seller is unbending--she refuses to come down on the price."*
- **Obstinate** - firmly or stubbornly adhering to a purpose. 

   A more negative characteristic in that there may not be a healthy or logical reason for holding their ground so firmly. 

   "The toddler was obstinate about not eating broccoli."
- **Unyielding** - hard; not apt to give under pressure. 

  Someone strong in their convictions or position, either wisely or unwisely. 

  "The wrestler's hold was unyielding. His opponent would have to tap out."
- **Uncompromising** - absolute; without exception. 

  Knows what they want and will take nothing else.

  "The chef is uncompromising when it comes to the quality of her ingredients."

Answer (score 1):

I would say **incorrigible**.

Cambridge Dictionary gives the following for its [definition](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/incorrigible):

> (of a person and their behavior) impossible to improve or correct: *an incorrigible liar*

It also gives the following explanation:

> An incorrigible person or incorrigible behaviour is bad and impossible to change or improve.

Comment: This is the most correct answer, if you ask me.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a precise word for that in the English language. Most would probably use an idiom like "a leopard can't change its spots" to express that notion. I would suggest rephrasing the line.